# deeplink juggernaut - remove settings

Tags: seo

I've used for a little while "SEO Ultimate" for Wordpress. Unfortunately the plugin demonstrated itself to be buggy and without a solid infrastructure on the back that would allow easy overriding of their functions.

Last but not least, their module called "link juggernaut" is a piece of cxxp as it links pages themself when it shouldn't and the most recent change that switched links presence from # to % utterly created more problems than ever.

In the end I moved to a different plugin. However, although the plugin removal, it appears the deep link juggernaut module are still doing something as I got my plain words converted into links without the link to be really there (not in the content at least).

Did anybody come across the same problem and found a solution?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: A solution to which part of your complaint, exactly?

Comment: @s_ha_dum clearly you didn't read my post nor have an understanding of the plugin itself as you criticized and negatively rated my question without knowing the topic. I am interested in a full removal of the autolinked keywords for which the deeplink juggernaut module was responsible.

Comment: I ask you to clarify your question. That is not criticism. Its just a question, and it is a fair question. You list several complaints, and mention two plugins-- only one of which you name--, and then ask if there is a solution "to the same problem". Also, [you don't know who down voted your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer) but the down vote can be removed by the down-voter or negated by someone else's upvote. You might want to reflect on why that hasn't happened and consider editing the question. Sincerely...

Comment: @s_ha_dum apologies for being so rude, I was in a bad mood yesterday. I have made a few tweaks to the post to make it more clear. I hope to find somebody able to come up with a solution. On their official forum the guys are not answering either.

Comment: Did the plugin rewrite post body content?

Comment: Well, even if this would be the case, being the plugin now gone, anything should be fine. But I don't have an answer for you. Where can I check this?

Comment: If the plugin rewrote the body content you should see anchor tags around the keywords in the HTML view of the backend post editor.

Comment: Anything noticeable in the HTML source code once in edit mode. I bet I have to look in the DB table for confirmation. If the plugin has left something behind, it may be the case it is rewriting content before the source is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Andrea,

I came across your post because I am experiencing the same problem.  Honestly, when I was deciding between ultimate and yoast, the juggernaut was a pro for me.  Not anymore, links are linking to themselves, and links in the h1 h2 h3 so forth, even when I set it not to.  I'll be switching to yoast, and find a plugin to do my deep linking automation.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers, Jackon! Answers are reserved for actual Answers to a Question. :) Once you've gained enough reputation by giving Answers that are chosen or voted up, you'll be able to comment on others' Questions and Answers.